# If condition within a PHP/HTML email file

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to display HTML table raw based on PHP `IF` condition but it is not working.

Can you please let me know what is wrong?

This code is part of a html email. I want to display the raw if the variable `$heating` is greater `0`.

**PHP code:**

```
<table border=\"1\">
    <tr>
        <td>Rental, cleaning and Taxes</td>
        <td align=right>$rent</td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($heating > 0) ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Pool heating</td>
        <td align=right>$heating</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <tr>
        <td>BBQ</td>
        <td align=right>$bbq</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Refundable Damage deposit</td>
        <td align=right>250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total(includes all taxes and fees</td>
        <td align=right>$total</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Email Display:**

```
Rental, cleaning and Taxes 1150 
Pool heating 0 
BBQ 50 
Refundable Damage deposit 250 
Total(includes all taxes and fees 1450
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to check out [AlphaMail](http://www.comfirm.se) to create and send your emails using [PHP](https://github.com/comfirm/alphamail-php5-client) and [Comlang](http://docs.amail.io/?section=comlang).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the alternate control structure syntax wrong:

```
<?php if ($heating > 0): ?>
                       ^--- missing
```

Without the colon, you're writing the equivalent of the one-liner

```
if (somecondition) 
   do_a_one_line_action;
```

Answer (score 1):

None of your variables are actually inside PHP code. They should be wrapped in `<?php echo $var; ?>`.  Apply the following pattern to all of your HTML-embedded PHP variables `$heating, $bbq, $total`.

```
// As in:
<td align='right'><?php echo $heating; ?></td>
```

See MarcB's answer above for the syntactic error on the templating `if` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
<?php if ($heating > 0) { ?>
<tr>
<td>Pool heating</td>
<td align=right><?=$heating?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it is displaying 0. It should display this raw only if heating is > 0

Comment: This is a PHP file and the entire code is enclosed in <? ... ?>

Comment: But you have HTML in the middle. So you might have closed PHP Tags. Else, how are you writing? Really Amazed with your reply @DanStanislaus

Comment: Dan, are you saying that your whole file is enclosed in php tag? I don't see that in your file as what @vijay-sarin is pointing out. Better provide more information in your question/comments than just replying to our answers that it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I presume this is in a variable such as:

```
HTMLtext = "<table border=\"1\">  
    <tr>  
    <td>Rental, cleaning and Taxes</td>  
    <td align=right>$rent</td></tr>  
    <?php if ($heating > 0) ?>  
    <tr>  
    <td>Pool heating</td>  
    <td align=right>$heating</td>  
    </tr>  
    <?php endif; ?>  
    <tr>  
    <td>BBQ</td>
    ....
"
```

In that case the PHP code won't be executed - it will be included in the string (and then striped out by the e-mail client)

You need to split into bits:

```
HTMLtext = "<table border=\"1\">  
    <tr>  
    <td>Rental, cleaning and Taxes</td>  
    <td align=right>$rent</td></tr>";

if ($heating > 0) {
    HTMLtext .= "
    <tr>  
    <td>Pool heating</td>  
    <td align=right>$heating</td>  
    </tr>";
}

HTMLtext .= "
    <tr>  
    <td>BBQ</td>
    ....
";
```

Comment: gah. don't do multiline string assignments. They're butt ugly, especially if you have quotes needing escaping. use [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s

Comment: He already has a multi-line assignment (you can tell by the escaped quotes already in the code) - so this is the neatest way of explaining the problem and solution.

Comment: here is the new codefee = \"
<table border=\"1\">
<tr>
<td>Rental, cleaning and Taxes</td>
<td align=right>$rent</td></tr>\"
if ($heating > 0){
fee . = \"
<tr>
<td>Pool heating</td>
<td align=right>$heating</td>
</tr>\"}
fee . = \"
<tr>
<td>BBQ</td>
<td align=right>$bbq</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Refundable Damage deposit</td>
<td align=right>250</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total(includes all taxes and fees</td>
<td align=right>$total</td>
</tr>
</table>\"
 
echo $fee;

Comment: Missed a semi-colon after the first quote, and at the end. See updated answer.